# Master Page cannot be loaded in C# ASP.Net publish

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am currently new to ASP.NET C# programming and have created a ASP.net Web application project in visual studio 2010, .NET 4.0. I have researched thoroughly to find a solution to my problem the last couple days but had no luck.

My issue is, debugging my project has no issues running on my local machine. I have a Site.Master page that is reference with a site.css. All my .ASPX pages run through the master site. However when i publish my website using File System
and setting my target location to my desktop, any call on a < href> tag to my default.aspx cannot load the site.master page. the error is as follows:

> "The Master Page file 'Site.Master' cannot be loaded.
>    Correct the problem in Code View".

now i do have IIS 7.5 installed, and i have tried to create a website through the inetmgr by following various steps through google searches and videos and still have no luck. is there something specific i am missing? everything is named the same in reference to stylesheet.

Comment: Is the master page present in the list of files that are published? - eg, public to a folder on the hard drive and check the master page is there. if the file is there, I would reflect the Web App dll, to make sure the compiled class is in there. It may be that the master page is set to content or something other than compile in the property browser.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to WraithNath's comment, might want to ensure IIS is configured to allow ASP.NET

Comment: "In addition to WraithNath's comment, might want to ensure IIS is configured to allow ASP.NET"

how would i configure it to allow ASP.net pages?

Comment: Open IIS config tool, and go to the application pools, find the app pool that your website is running under, and view advanced settings. Also, you might want to look at the ISAPI restrictions to ensure .NET hasn't been restricted